# Asynchronous workers with .NET Core

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

There is a pool of producers (100-200). Each producer fills its own queue of workitems. Solution must process those producers' queues evenly (FIFO): basically round-robin through different producers' queues and take its oldest workitem at a time to processing. Some queues might be empty and a few might contain as much data as all the others combined.

The easy way would be to assign each producer its own thread, but that would be inefficient because of the large number of context switching needed and because workitems consist mainly of IO-tasks (nothing CPU intensive)

I was thinking of implementing a small pool of worker thread's that process those queues asynchronously in round-robin manner, but how should this be implemented? Or is there a better way?

Performance is the biggest driving factor here so it should be able to utilize each CPU core with as little blocking as possible and process those queues evenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

Or the newer Channels API:

- [An Introduction to System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/)
- [Channelling my inner geek](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2016/09/channelling-my-inner-geek.html)
- [.NET INTERNALS: SYSTEM.THREADING.CHANNELS – UNBOUNDEDCHANNEL (PART 1)](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/dotnet-internals-system-threading-channels-unboundedchannel-part-1), [.NET INTERNALS: SYSTEM.THREADING.CHANNELS – UNBOUNDEDCHANNEL PART 2](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/dotnet-internals-system-threading-channels-unboundedchannel-part-2) and [.NET INTERNALS: SYSTEM.THREADING.CHANNELS – UNBOUNDEDCHANNEL PART 3](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/dotnet-internals-system-threading-channels-unboundedchannelt-part-3)